# Android bluetooth voice chat, smartphone as a headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, voice, headset

I have a task at my work to make an android smartphone as a bluetooh headset. I mean that I need to connect from my phone to some device (radiomodem) that supports bluetooth (it will be server) and I need to send and recieve sound from a smartphone to this device via SCO protocol. I've found some app in PlayMarket that make voice bluetooth chat between two smartphones. They work rather good, but I don't have any idea how do they make this. Has anybody tried to write such application? Has anybody seen some source code?

Thanks.